# How do I reference my speed value that's from another script and incorporate it into my movement script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop

all, I'm making my second ever game and I can't quite figure this out. The game has classes, where each class has a different speed. I'm trying to implement movement by taking the value of the speed.

I have the getters/setters for the different parts of the class [Getters/setters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CynJA.png)
I've tested that the values do get assigned to the variables in the class selection, and all is good there I think.

I'm working on my movement script and I cant quite see where I've gone wrong, I've tried the GetComponent<> function [GetComponent function added to an in-script variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoGYR.png)
but when I try this it says the PlayerSpeed variable doesn't exist in the current context and the player doesn't move. I've also tried scrapping the in class variable and directly using getcomponent<> but that didn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post your code, not images of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `Start` does nothing.

```
private void Start ()
{
    float PlayerSpeed = GetComponent<BasePlayerClass>()._Speed;
}
```

this stores the speed value in a **local variable** that only exists within the scope of `Start` and is never used for anything at all.

If something at all you would need a class field

```
private float PlayerSpeed;
```

and then initialize it

```
private void Start ()
{
    PlayerSpeed = GetComponent<BasePlayerClass>()._Speed;
}
```

---

**However**, in general it is bad practice to store the same value in multiple places - especially if the speed is supposed to be dynamically changed later on, have in mind that `float` is a **value type** which means what you store is a **copy** of the value rather than a reference.

You would rather do

```
[SerializeField] private BasePlayerClass basePlayerClass;

private void Start ()
{
    if(!basePlayerClass) basePlayerClass = GetComponent<BasePlayerClass>();
}
```

and then later on directly access and use

```
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * basePlayerClass._Speed);
```

---

In general the naming with `_` for `public` members is a bit unconventional / counterintuitive.

Usually you would go

```
public SomeType SomeName;
//Or
public SomeType someName;
```

And then accordingly go

```
private SomeType someType;
// Or respectively
private SomeType _someType;
```

Specific to Unity I personally prefer

```
public SomeType SomeName;
private SomeType _someName;
[SerializeField] private SomeType someName;
```